# Getiing error while converting a dataframe to a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

Below is the code, imported the data to data frame but unable to convert it into a list. Getting TypeError:'list' object is not callable

```
import pandas
import numpy
import random
dataframe = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
list= ['Gender']
dataset = dataframe.drop(list, axis=1)
print(list(dataset))
```

Answer (score 3):

You created a variable called `list`, so when you try to call the `list` constructor, you're met with an error, since `list` now refers to a `list`, instead of a type constructor.  Don't use builtin names as variable names.

You could also just use `dataset.columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 3):

Problem is code variable `list` as variable name, better is use `L`.

Solution is reassign `list` by `list = builtins.list` or after rename variable restart your IDE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import builtins

#reassign list
list = builtins.list

dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
L = ['Gender']
dataset = dataframe.drop(L, axis=1)
#if want columns names in list
print(list(dataset))
#if want all values of df to nested lists
print(dataset.values.tolist())
```

Comment: @user3483203 - Thank you.

Comment: You can also del list

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can override language keywords and data types, in your case - the `list` data type.
Have a look:

```
print('type of list: {0}'.format(type(list)))
list = ['Gender']
print('type of list: {0}'.format(type(list)))
```

outputs:

```
type of list: <type 'type'>
type of list: <type 'list'>
```

I would suggest changing your variable name to something other than `list`